# Meteor - client can't get the collection

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

I'm still trying to get my head around the whole publish/subscribe aspect of Meteor.

This is the gist of what I'm trying to achieve.

On server side, at "Meteor.startup", I grab RSS feeds from a blog. This part works. Basically, my server code looks like

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection "items"

Meteor.startup ->
  ..
  .. # code for fetching the RSS feeds
  ..
  for each feed
    Items.insert
      title:item.title

  console.log Items.find().count() # this returns the correct count

  Meteor.publish "items", ->
    Items.find()
```

Now that I have published the "items", I want to subscribe to it from the client.

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection "items"
Meteor.subscribe("items")
console.log Items.find().count()
```

But above gives me "0".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subsribing is asynchronous, you need to wait for the subscription to be completed by passing a callback function before trying to access the data in the collection.  Example in Javascript:

```
Meteor.subscribe('items', function () {
    console.log(Items.find().count());
});
```

Comment: i found out this is not reactive. where else i could count the collection items and reactive if there is any data changes occur.